# Display the 'File -> Print' menu via VBA

Tags: excel, printing, vba

Using VBA for Excel (2010) I can call both the print dialog and the print preview, but I cannot figure out how to call the **File -> Print** menu.

```
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogPrint).Show ' Client - "not in keeping with the Excel 2010 experience"
ActiveSheet.PrintPreview (False)        ' Very slow to display
```

Is it possible to display this menu option using VBA?

Comment: Were you referring to the screen you get with this: `application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "PrintPreviewAndPrint"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you are trying?

`Sendkeys` are unreliable so you have to be very careful while using them.

Ensure that you call it from Developer Tab | Macros and not directly from the VBA Editor. Else you will have to use APIs to bring the Excel window to the front and then use sendkeys.

```
Sub Sample()
    SendKeys "%fp"
End Sub
```

Here is an example to call it from VBE

```
Private Declare Function SetForegroundWindow _
Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long

Sub Sample()
    Dim CBC As CommandBarControl

    '~~> Bring the Excel window to the front.
    '~~> I am assuming that there is only one excel instance
    '~~> If there are more then you will have to use Findwindow,
    '~~> FindwindowEx API
    SetForegroundWindow ActiveWorkbook.Application.hWnd

    '~~> Closing the VBE
    On Error Resume Next
    Set CBC = Application.VBE.CommandBars.FindControl(ID:=752)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not CBC Is Nothing Then
        CBC.Execute
        DoEvents

        '~~> File --> Print
        SendKeys "%fp"
    End If
End Sub
```